# Using Github repo in Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, github, github-for-windows

I am using Github repo in my own app and uploading the app to play store is illegal?
Should I have to state about License and copyrights of the owner of that library in my app?

Comment: That depends on the license of the library you are using - but Stack Overflow is not the place for legal advice, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the license that is provided in the repo.